# How to correctly specify mail from header in tomat mail session

Tags: java, email, tomcat7

I have a configured a mail session as follows in tomcat.

```
<Resource name="mail/test" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
        mail.smtp.auth="true"
        mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
        mail.smtp.port="587"
        mail.smtp.user="anotheruseratgmail@gmail.com"
        password="*******************"
        mail.smtp.from="anotheruseratgmail@gmail.com"
        mail.smtp.quitwait="false"
        mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
        mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
        mail.debug="true"/>
```

That work fine. But now I want to add my name in the from header.

```
  <Resource name="mail/test" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
            mail.smtp.auth="true"
            mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
            mail.smtp.port="587"
            mail.smtp.user="anotheruseratgmail@gmail.com"
            password="*******************"
            **mail.smtp.from="My Name &lt;anotheruseratgmail@gmail.com&gt;"**
            mail.smtp.quitwait="false"
            mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
            mail.debug="true"/>
```

The above configuration fails. Gmail sends a syntax error

555 5.5.2 Syntax error. fu1sm2278788wic.2 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 555, with response: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. fu1sm2278788wic.2 - gsmtp

Answer (score 0):

See if you can catch a log of the conversation with the server. My greatest concern would be if those `&lt;` and `&gt;`s are getting evaluated. Obviously, if they aren't, the SMTP server won't be happy about it.